# Configuring Single Sign On using WSO2

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm following [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Single+Sign-On) "official" document, but when, finally, I click any of the "SAML" links, I get this error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/X509KeyManager;Ljavax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
    org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeHttpClient(DefaultBootstrap.java:118)
    org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultBootstrap.java:110)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.util.SSOAgentUtils.doBootstrap(SSOAgentUtils.java:110)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.<init>(SAML2SSOManager.java:135)
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentFilter.doFilter(SSOAgentFilter.java:129)
    org.wso2.sample.is.sso.agent.SSOAgentSampleFilter.doFilter(SSOAgentSampleFilter.java:107)
```

Has anyone tried this, or has something to suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: ...and why do you think there should be a negative vote? Please care to suggest, how else should I put it? or where else should I ask this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We, me and my colleague, found that, it includes older version of `openws`, namely, `1.4.1`.

In order to fix this, one needs to modify `pom.xml`, of parent, `product-is`, to,

```
...
<openws.version>1.5.4</openws.version>
...
```

from

```
...
<openws.version>1.4.1</openws.version>
...
```

Further, probably, one needs to add Maven Central repo exclusively in the `pom.xml`, like below

```
...
<repository>
    <id>central-exclusive</id>
    <name>Maven Central</name>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven/</url>
</repository>
...
```

Doing that will enable you to pass that error, but just to hit another hinderance. But that is something else -- something to do with configuration, nevertheless.

**NB: `1.5.4` works for me; there might be some other version having that intended constructor.**